# Логирование бинарных данных

Tags: java, логирование, log4j

Хочу прикрутить к log4j возможность логирования бинарных данных. По сути мне нужно принять `byte[]` и отдать его в appender.

Как-то так

```
byte[] data = {1, 2, 3};
log.debug(data);
```

Вопросы:

1. Есть ли уже стандартный Layout для такой логики или нужно писать своего наследника от `MessageLayout`
2. Если писать своего наследника, то как-бы его объявить, чтобы на него можно было ссылаться из конфигурационного XML файла?

**Update**

Как оказалось, одного Layout мало. Нужны еще манипуляции с интерфейсом `Message`

Обнаружилась такая проблема

при вызове

```
byte[] data = {1, 2, 3};
log.debug(data);
```

я попадаю в метод `log` класса `LoggerConfig` и там выполняется такая строчка

```
LogEvent logEvent = this.logEventFactory.createEvent(loggerName, marker, fqcn, level, data, (List)props, t);
```

где `data` объект класса `ReusableObjectMessage` у которого в поле `obj` лежит мой массив.

Далее идет вызов

```
public LogEvent createEvent(String loggerName, Marker marker, String fqcn, Level level, Message message, List<Property> properties, Throwable t) {
    MutableLogEvent result = (MutableLogEvent)mutableLogEventThreadLocal.get();
    ............
    result.setMessage(message);
    ............
}
```

А метод `MutableLogEvent.setMessage` реализован так

```
public void setMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg instanceof ReusableMessage) {
        ReusableMessage reusable = (ReusableMessage)msg;
        reusable.formatTo(this.getMessageTextForWriting());
        this.messageFormat = msg.getFormat();
        if (this.parameters != null) {
            this.parameters = reusable.swapParameters(this.parameters);
            this.parameterCount = reusable.getParameterCount();
        }
    } else {
        this.message = InternalAsyncUtil.makeMessageImmutable(msg);
    }
}
```

На строке

```
reusable.formatTo(this.getMessageTextForWriting());
```

идет жесткое преобразование объекта в строку
а попытка обменяться параметрами

```
this.parameters = reusable.swapParameters(this.parameters);
```

приводит к фикции

```
public Object[] swapParameters(final Object[] emptyReplacement) {
    return emptyReplacement;
}
```

хотя сами параметры у Message определены

```
public Object[] getParameters() {
    return new Object[] {obj};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итого получилось:

1. Реализуем свой Layout

   ```
   @Plugin(
       name = "BinaryLayout",
       category = "Core",
       elementType = "layout",
       printObject = true
   )
   public class BinaryLayout extends MessageLayout {
       @Override
       public byte[] toByteArray(LogEvent event) {
           Object[] params = event.getMessage().getParameters();
           int size = 0;
           int count = 0;
           byte[] res = null;
           for (Object obj : params) {
               if (obj instanceof byte[]) {
                   byte[] tmp = (byte[])obj;
                   if (tmp.length > 0) {
                       size += tmp.length;
                       count++;
                       res = tmp;
                   }
               }
           }
           if (count > 1) {
               res = new byte[size];
               size = 0;
               for (Object obj : params) {
                   if (obj instanceof byte[]) {
                       byte[] tmp = (byte[])obj;
                       if (tmp.length > 0) {
                           System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, res, size, tmp.length);
                           size += tmp.length;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           return res;
       }

       @PluginFactory
       public static Layout<?> createLayout() {
           return new BinaryLayout();
       }
   }
   ```

   - Аннотация `@Plugin` говорит, что упоминания в конфиге `name = "BinaryLayout"` это к нам. Категория для layout должна быть `Core`, а иначе наш layout не находится, `elementType` и так ясно, а `printObject` говорит, что метод `toString` у нас не переопределен и печатать наш объект бессмысленно
   - Аннотация `@PluginFactory` определяет фабричный метод, который создаст наш layout
2. <del>Реализуем интерфейс `Message`</del> При записи в лог используем объект класса `ObjectMessage`. Т.к. этот класс не является наследником `ReusableMessage`, то при создании объекта `LogEvent` не теряются наши данные
3. Объявляем в конфиге appender с нашим layout

   ```
   <Appenders>
     <File name="test" filename="log/test.log" append="false">
       <BinaryLayout/>
     </File>
   </Appenders>
   ```
4. И, собственно, само использование

   ```
   Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("test");
   byte[] data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
   log.debug(new ObjectMessage(data));
   ```